# binomial normal with dependent success probability

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution, probability-limit-theorems

Suppose $Z$ is a random variable distributed according to binomial distribution $B(n,p)$. For constant $p$ it is known that the distribution can be well approximated by the normal distribution. If $pn$ is constant, then it converge to a Poisson distribution. What in the intermidiate case? For example to what is the limit distribution for $p=\Omega(\log(n)/n)$? Is there any known theorem, which specifies this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Poisson approximation still works in the $p=\Omega(\log( n)/n)$ case. According to [Le Cam's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Cam%27s_theorem), the [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation#Total_variation_of_probability_measures) between the actual binomial distribution and its approximating Poisson distribution is of order $np^2$, which in your case is $O((\log n)^2/n)$.  Also note that the Poisson distribution with large expectation (in your case, $O(\log n)$) is itself approximated by the CLT, but not in total variation.

The specifics of your application will dictate both the order of growth of $pn$ and the desired degree of approximation of distributions, so I hesitate to give one recipe that fits all occasions.  If, for instance, $np\to\infty$ and $np^2\to 0$, the Binomial is well approximated by the Poisson and the Poisson, after rescaling, by the Gaussian.  If $np^2\to0$ but $np$ remains bounded, you lose the Gaussian approximation but retain the Poisson.  But if $p=\Omega(1/\log n)$ Le Cam's inequality looses grip, at least when used this way.

Comment: So what is the threshold value for which I cannot approximate binomial distribution by Normal distribution? is it simply $pn=\omega(1)$?

Comment: I have tried to address this in an edit to my answer.